# Launching Activity via Intent Viewer and browser address bar - nothing happens - only when clicking link

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm attempting to launch an activity from the browser (which simply displays a warning icon) when a user accesses a website however when I add the intent filter to my AndroidManifest.xml the application never launches the new activity upon loading the URL.

The only way it will load is if it's a link to the url (such as in an email) instead of when the user actually pulls up www.playboy.com

Any suggestions?

- Amani

MANIFEST

```
<activity
        android:name="com.app.Warning"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>  
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>  
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>  
<data android:host="playboy.com" android:scheme="http"></data>  
</intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, copy Google.  The Play Store and YouTube apps both use some sort of path specification in their intent-filters.  Try something like `pathPrefix="/"`.

The manifest for Google Play Store includes the line:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="market.android.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
```

Comment: Strange... the google play store launches when visiting market.android.com but mine still never launches:

    <activity
        android:name="com.app.linked.Warning"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>  
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>  
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>  
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="playboy.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />  
</intent-filter> 
    </activity>

Comment: Will this work via the browser address bar? (The google market launches this way) from what I'm reading this is designed to work via a link within the app - I'm looking for a way to do this from the browser directly.

Comment: it should definitely work from within a link on a web page.  i've seen mixed results from trying to intercept links typed manually into a browser address bar; a browser may simply load the page or (if it's not http(s)) show an error instead of activating the android app.

Comment: I need it to launch typed manually in the browser bar (it's a parental control app - the users will be typing urls into the browser bar 99.99% of the time)

Comment: That was it! Adding android:pathPrefix="/" resolved the issue! I can now launch the app by typing the URL in the browser!

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the "www":

```
<data android:host="playboy.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
```

And check if your Browser is set as default App for this Host. 
There is still one issue with your implementation: When it works, Android will show a chooser Dialog when the user surfs on playboy.com, asking the user to open this Adress with browser of with your app. Only if the user clicks on your App, it will be started, otherwise it will continue in browser just like now. I don't think this is the behaviour you want to achieve.

Comment: I updated the url to display just playboy.com however when I open my app then click home and open the browser - it still never prompts me to open it with my app.

Comment: it's strange... the google play store opens when visiting market.android.com but nothing happens when I launch playboy.com 

(I updated my source code above)

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I'd like to achieve... (but it isn't working - any additional suggestions?)